# Joint density of $X, Y$ and $X+ Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, linear-transformations

Suppose $(X, Y)$ has the joint density $f(x,y)$. Let $\mathbf{Z} = [X+Y, X, Y]^\top = \mathbf{A}[X, Y]^\top$ where

$$
\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If $(X, Y)$ is multivariate normal, then the density of $\mathbf{Z}$ is some constant times $f(x,y)$. The constant depends on $\mathbf{A}$.

Does this relationship hold for any distribution?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson it is equivalent to the pseudo determinant of $\mathbf{A}$, in the Gaussian setting.

Comment: If $(X, Y)$ is multinormal, $Z$ does not have a density! What are you really thinking?

Comment: @WillM. I think the density exists in the subspace of $R^3$.

Comment: I think you mean in a plane. Maybe there is something related to densities in manifolds, but honestly, I got my PhD in probability and never saw or used something related to that. Now, I am aware that there is a new topic "hot" in statistics known as "topological statistics" (or "topological data analysis") in which they do statistics in manifolds. Maybe check that.